# Scala type parameters for objects

Tags: scala, object, type-parameter

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593487/scala-passing-type-parameters-to-object), however I can't see how using existential types would help in my case.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
type MonadicArithmeticFunc[S] = (Int, S) => (Int, S)

object addOne[S] extends MonadicArithmeticFunc[S] {
  def apply(n: Int, s: S): (Int, S) = (n + 1, s)
}

val state = Seq.empty[Int]
println(addOne(4, state))
```

However this doesn't work as one cannot add a type parameter to an object. I tried using an existential type also:

```
object addOne extends MonadicArithmeticFunc[_] {
  def apply[S](n: Int, s: S): (Int, S) = (n + 1, s)
}
```

But of course that doesn't work either, as the apply method isn't what takes the type parameter in `Function2`.

I could use a basic def:

```
def addOne[S](n: Int, s: S): (Int, S) = (n + 1, s)
```

except I'd have to declare that in a package object to get the same scoping. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is no point in what you'r trying to achieve, your ArithmeticFunc is not monadic in any sense and no reason to use it as superclass, cause you can simply write `object addOne { def apply[S](n: Int, s: S): (Int, S) = (n + 1, s) }`. Can you elaborate on what you'r trying to do, it looks like either type class pattern would make your life easier or scalaz State monad

Comment: Just curious: why would you avoid putting something in a package object?

Comment: I guess the problem is that I want to be able to use `addOne` as a function object, and use it in various cases where the type of `S` varies. This would be ok, because `addOne` doesn't care what S is: it's just passing it through. But now I realise that's not going to be possible in the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

It simply doesn't make sense to have type parameters (or constructor parameters, for that matter) for an `object`, because `addOne[Int]` and `addOne[String]` would be (presumably) different objects, but the keyword `object` means there only should be one object. You could have

```
class addOne[S] extends MonadicArithmeticFunc[S] {
  def apply(n: Int, s: S): (Int, S) = (n + 1, s)
}

object addOne {
  def apply[S] = new addOne[S]
}
```

if you really need `MonadicArithmeticFunc` for some reason. But as Alexlv says,

```
object addOne {
  def apply[S](n: Int, s: S) = (n + 1, s)
}
```

would normally be preferable.

Comment: I like the class + object example. I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, I can see that is the limitation of the JVM: there are discretely different objects for each type. Because `addOne` doesn't care what the actual type of `S` is, I was hoping to have just a single runtime object for that Function2 - basically have `S` be `Object` at runtime - but without any casting. I guess I'll just need to allocate separate instances of `addOne` for every type.